# Effects of Scaling on Matrix Norms

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I feel as though is a very stupid question, but I'm struggling to muddle through it so here I am.

For Gauss-Seidel methods one way to formulate the convergence requirement is that given the system $Ax=b$ and a set of iteration matrices $\{T_{i}\}$, for some natural matrix norm, $\forall i,||T_{i}||<1$. If we take the case of the $L_{2}$ norm, then $||A||_{2}=max(\sigma_{i})$ where $\sigma_{i}$ are the singular values of $A$.

My question is this: Say $||A||_{2}=40$. Is it not possible to apply a scaling factor to $A$ such that for all possible iteration matrices $T$, $||T||_{2}<1$ (like, $A_{scale}=\frac{1}{1000000}A$)?

My intuition tells me this must be incorrect somehow because otherwise there would be no reason why Gauss-Seidel methods would ever fail to converge (we would simply apply said scaling factor to any system). What am I missing, or is this actually correct?

Comment: You have to actually use the iteration matrix that Gauss-Seidel specifies, so that the fixed point of the iteration matrix is actually the solution to $Ax=b$. Rescaling $T$ would reduce its norm, which would force convergence to its fixed point, but you'd get the wrong fixed point.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm saying the scaling would be applied to $A$ (and presumably $b$) such that the iteration matrix $T$ that results from the system automatically has $L_{2}$ norm < 1. Or is what you are saying that by scaling $A$ and $b$ in such a manner you would end up with a "faulty" $T$?

Comment: Applying it to just $A$ doesn't necessarily rescale $T$, look at what $T$ actually is.

Comment: Given $Ax=b$, the transition from $x^{k}$ to $x^{k+1}$ when using Gauss-Seidel is defined as $(D+L)x^{k+1}=-Ux^{k}+b$, where $U,D,L$ are defined conventionally for Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel iterations. From this, we can see the matrix we want to analyze for spectral radius is $-(D+L)^{-1}U$. This matrix is clearly dependent on $A$, so how does scaling $A$ _not_ affect $-(D+L)^{-1}U$?

Comment: It actually won't even change it--the inverse part gets scaled the opposite of how the $U $ part gets scaled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $T(A)=-(D+L)^{-1}U$:

$$T(cA)=-(cD+cL)^{-1}cU=-c^{-1}(D+L)^{-1}cU=-(D+L)^{-1}U=T(A).$$

Thus the iteration matrix is not changed at all by rescaling $A$. So although you can just as well solve $Ax=b$ or $(cA)x=cb$, Gauss-Seidel's convergence and convergence rate are not affected.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was missing something obvious!